# remove elements from collection with underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

i want with underscore remove from a collection like this

```
[{cod:"1", Desc: "Description1"}, {cod:"2", Desc: "Description2"}]
```

all item except a certain cod, for example 1.

How can i do?

I know that i can search with for statement, but is possible avoid it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var test = [{cod:"1", Desc: "Description1"}, 
            {cod:"2", Desc: "Description2"},];

var t = _.without(test, _.findWhere(test, {cod: "1"}));

alert(JSON.stringify(t));
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rZxW9/)**

Answer (score 2):

You don’t even need Underscore for that.

```
var filtered = arr.filter(function (item) {
    return item.cod !== "1";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) function, like this

```
console.log(_.filter(array, function(currentItem) {
    return currentItem.cod !== "1";
}));
# [ { cod: '2', Desc: 'Description2' } ]
```

Or you can use [`_.reject`](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) function, like this

```
console.log(_.reject(array, function(currentItem) {
    return currentItem.cod === "1";
}));
# [ { cod: '2', Desc: 'Description2' } ]
```

Or you can use the native [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), like this

```
console.log(array.filter(function(currentItem) {
    return currentItem.cod !== "1";
}));
# [ { cod: '2', Desc: 'Description2' } ]
```